# How a change a dash size?

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I have a small size of dash
How I can change a dash size or a parent div size? I used a simple usage from example and it worked normal. But I have size problem with new dash

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

dash app

```
 import dash 
 import dash_core_components as dcc
 import dash_html_components as html

from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample')   # replaces dash.Dash

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

html.Div(children='''
    Dash: A web application framework for Python.
'''),

dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure={
        'data': [
            {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
            {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
        }
    }
)])  if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import plotly_app



 def index(request):
     return render(request, "index.html")
```

some important from settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'newtry',
'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',]
```

Default size of parent div is 0.
I used a many graphs and size is 0.
I think it can be depends on simple usage size form. But i can't change this

```html
<div style="
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10.0%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    ">
  <iframe src="/django_plotly_dash/app/SimpleExample/" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    " frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: <div style="
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10.0%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    ">
  <iframe src="/django_plotly_dash/app/SimpleExample/" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    " frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>  parent div have     height: 0;

Comment: default height of parent div is 0